# If $E$ has pullbacks then $\text{SplitEpi}(E)$ has pullbacks

Tags: category-theory, diagram-chasing

The book *From groups to Categorical Algebra* has as exercise to prove that if $E$ has pullbacks then the category of split epimorphisms of $E$ has pullbacks. This category consists of split epimorphisms along with a fixed section as objects, and the morphisms are commutative squares such that the diagrams restricted to only having the split epimorphisms and only having the sections commute. By drawing a messy diagram and trying to "chase" equal morphisms, i believe i was able to prove this. It was already a lot of work to do this on paper so for obvious reasons i won't try doing it in LaTex (if requested i can post picture). Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: A more precise referene to the exercise (e.g. number in section in chapter) would be helpful.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov exercise 1.5.6 from chapter 1

Answer (score 0):

One way is to realize the category of of split epimorphisms in $E$ as a category of functors, and then prove the more general fact that (co)limits in categories of functors valued in a category may be computed "pointwise" from (co)limits in the category. This is the same amount of effort as the direct proof, but with a more general result, and thus more efficient.

Comment: How do you realise $\text{SplitEpi}(E)$ as a category of functors here? My first thought was having $D$ as the category consisting of a free epimorphism with section, but if morphisms are commutative squares, wouldn't this imply that there's only morphisms between isomorphisms?

Comment: If the free category has a section $A\to B$ and a retraction $B\to A$, two functors $F$ and $G$ correspond to sections $FA\to FB$ of $FB\to FA$, and $GA\to GB$ of $GB\to GA$, while a natural transformation between them is two morphisms $FA\to GA$ and $FB\to GB$, such that you have two commutative squares, one for each (generating) morphism in $D$: $FA\to FB\to GB$ same as $FA\to GA\to GB$ and $FB\to FA\to GA$ same as $FB\to GB\to GA$.